# WebUIValidation.js tries to access properties in an incorrect way? Fails

Tags: javascript, validation

[WebUIValidation.js](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/CF1BCAF2/98B968D5) is a pretty standard form validation script used in many .NET solutions.

Spans are used as validators, they can look something like this

```
<span id="myDateControl" data-val-evaluationfunction="RangeValidatorEvaluateIsValid" data-val="true" data-val-errormessage="invalid date" data-val-controltovalidate="myDateControl" type="Date" minimumvalue="1990-01-01" maximumvalue="2013-12-18" style="visibility:hidden;"><span class="Validate Error"></span></span>
```

What the script does is select these span elements and tries to access properties on the objects using dot notation.

The problem is that the minimumvalue and maximumvalue properties can't be accessed by the validation code.
(I've just added these properties to my span. Previously I just did other types of validations and everything worked fine)
Looking at the code, the 'function RangeValidatorEvaluateIsValid(val)' tries to access 'val.minimunvalue' which is undefined. the 'val' object in that case is just a span element and the the property 'minimumvalue' cannot be accessed using dot notation, only using 'getAttribute("minimumvalue")'. Same thing with maximumvalue

The weird thing is other properties such as 'controltovalidate' and 'errormessage' CAN be accessed using dot notation.
So I'm wondering if some properties are dynamically added to the 'val' object, but I've searched through all the code in my project without finding anything like that...

Need some help please. Is the code in WebUIValidation.js incorrect? 
Or are properties added on the 'val' object some way that I haven't noticed?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `data-val-` prefix to the attribute names? I mean, `data-val-minimumvalue` and `data-val-maximumvalue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `data-val-` prefix to the attribute names:

```
... data-val-minimumvalue=... data-val-maximumvalue=...
```